# Permanent Redirect While Keeping Same URL Path

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a new domain I want my old domain to be redirected to while keeping the same url path. This is what I have came up with and is working great.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my_new_site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

However, there is one folder name I have changed. The search engines are caching with that old folder name. I need that folder name to reflect the new name after it has been redirected to the new domain while keeping the same path. So....

old path -> old_domain.com/old_folder_name/but/keep/same/url/path.html

new path -> new_domain.com/new_folder_name/but/keep/same/url/path.html